# Getting Exact Latitude and Longitude GMaps.Net

Tags: gmap.net

I am using **WinForms alongside with GMaps.Net**.

I wanted to get the exact latitude and longitude of the marker so I used the OnClickMarker handler.

I tried using myVar.Location where it only returns the X, Y values according to the scale of the map and not the latitude and longitude of the actual location.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can convert the x,y coordinates to latitude, longitude by using the method **FromLocalToLatLng**, like the below example:

```
Private Sub GMapControl1_OnMarkerClick(item As GMapMarker, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GMapControl1.OnMarkerClick
       Dim pt as PointLatLng = GMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y)
       MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Latitude: {0}, Longitude: {1}",pt.Lat, pt.Lng))
End Sub
```